# Cannot generate a 64 bit long value in java

Tags: java, 64-bit

Recently I developed interest in bit manipulation and arithmetic. I am planning to write a code to represent a chess board using a 64 bit long variable where each bit represents a cell.

I encountered an issue as below:

```
public class Chess {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long v = (1 << 63 ) - 1;
    System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE+ " " +v);
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(v));
    System.out.println(Long.bitCount(v));
}

}
```

Following is the output of the above code:

```
9223372036854775807 2147483647
1111111111111111111111111111111
31
```

which is not correct.

I am expecting a 64 bit binary string. I am using a 64 bit machine with 64 bit Windows OS.

Please help.

Comment: `1 << 63` == `1 << 31` == `1 << -1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an `int` literal, so when attempting to bit-shift by `63`, only the last 5 bits of `63` are considered -- `31`.

Use a `long` literal (append "L") to bit-shift:

```
long v = (1L << 63 ) - 1;
```

The [JLS, Section 15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19), covers bit-shifting details:

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the **five lowest-order bits** of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance.

(emphasis mine)

That makes sense -- there are only 32 bits in an `int`, or 2^5.

Also,

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is long, then only the six lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance.

That again makes sense -- there are 64 bits in a `long`, or 2^6.

Comment: thank you very much.. I was trying the "L" in a wrong way .. I love SO